# How to return value to global variable from asyn/await function?

Tags: javascript

I want to return the user's geolocation to the variable so other function can use it later. I tried using async/await function but it doesn't work. What have I done wrong?

```
// Getting data
class Data {
  static async getLatitude() {
    let latitude = await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      return position.coords.latitude;
    });
    return latitude;
  }

}


// Site running
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    let latitude = Data.getLatitude();
    console.log(latitude);

  }
})
```

Comment: Your handler needs the keyword await. `await Data.getLatitude()` that will resolve the promise before moving to the next statement

Comment: 3 options you have is, callback, promise or async/await method. It is not practical to store output in a variable while doing async programming. Better look for patterns for working with async functions.

Comment: You're almost there. Try `let latitude = await Data.getLatitude();`. What you have will set `latitude` to the promise that resolves to the latitude rather than the latitude itself.

Comment: @ali the OP is already trying to use async await, they're just missing a few keywords

Comment: @PatrickStephansen but I can use await only in async function so it doesn't work

Comment: My mistake. You also need to make the second argument to the `window.addEventListener` function async: `window.addEventListener('load', async () => {`

Comment: @PatrickStephansen yeah, I tried this but it is displaying then the undefined value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` does not return a `Promise`. That's why you can't use async/await to get its response. You will have to wrap that into a Promise yourself to be able to use async/await to get the result. Here is the full code:

```
class Data {
  static async getLatitude() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        resolve(position.coords.latitude);
      }, reject);
    });
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    let latitude = await Data.getLatitude();
    console.log(latitude);

  }
})
```